# Animate sidebar with framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to animate sidebar to hide it from right to left in my NextJS 13 app. For that I'm using `framer-motion` from [this](https://youtu.be/YELPZw5ieHQ?si=JanA82xj2MPzjxrA&t=731) tutorial. But the problem is `motion.div` doesn't affect my sidebar if I use `open` or `closed`.

```
'use client'

import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

export default function Sidebar() {
  const variants = {
    open: {
      width: '16rem',
      transition: {
        damping: 40,
      },
    },
    closed: {
      width: '4rem',
      transition: {
        damping: 40,
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <motion.div
        animate={'closed'}
        variants={variants}
        className=" bg-white text-gray shadow-xl z-[999] max-w-[16rem]
        w-[16rem] overflow-hidden md:relative fixed h-screen"
      ></motion.div>
    </div>
  )
}
```